# How do I View Pending Changes on My Computer before Restarting It?

Tags: windows-7, updates

So... my cat jumped up onto my keyboard and hit a bunch of buttons. When the computer finally unfroze, a dialogue window popped up saying that the changes I had made to my computer would not take place until I restart it. What?!? What changes? What did this cat do? The only options were restart now or restart later - no cancel the changes option.

How can I view these pending changes (and perhaps also cancel them) before restarting my computer? I have Windows 7. I managed to find a similar question here, but it did not have a satisfactory answer.

- I'm going to have to answer the comments here. For some reason, it looks like I'm not able to comment on my own post since it thinks I'm commenting on someone else's post (since I'm logged in as a guest) and I don't have enough reputations to do that.
- The title of the dialogue box was "Microsoft Windows". Not sure if this helps any. I guess if I'm out of luck then I may as well restart my computer and see what happens, lol.
- It is possible the update or change is unrelated to the cat. In my experience, though, the pending updates dialogue box has a big yellow banner on it and says the words "pending update" somewhere in there instead of "pending changes". That's why I'm thinking this cat is the culprit.
- Thanks for your help you guys.

Comment: What was the title of the dialog? Generally pending changes aren't stored in a list anywhere - They've already been committed to disk, and the restart is just to get the kernel and services to re-read the configuration. Unless you have a backup to compare against, you might be out of luck.

Comment: Is it possible your system was simply going to install a patch and the cat event was not connected.

Comment: `Generally pending changes aren't stored in a list anywhere`   @DarthAndroid, sure they are; they’re in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations. If we’re talking about Windows Updates, then they are stored in `C:\Windows\WinSxS\reboot.xml` and `C:\Windows\WinSxS\pending.xml`.

Answer (score 5):

If it was the [Windows Update notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHN6d.png) (which you indicated it probably was not), then you could check the files `pending.xml` and `reboot.xml` in `C:\Windows\WinSxS`, but Windows Updates are expected and you can’t/don’t want to cancel them.

If it was something else, you can use a program like [MoveLater](http://bitsum.com/other/#movelatr) or [PendMoves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pendmoves) to examine (or modify) the registry entry `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations` which has a list of files and directories that Windows has scheduled for renaming, moving, or deleting at the next reboot.

Comment: I had a similar issue as OP, with the same window title (the same window that appears after you modify the boot items with msconfig.exe), and I found some info in the reboot.xml file. However there wasn't the pending.xml file, and PendMoves could not find anything. So it seems that reboot.xml will also appear when there are pending changes other than from Windows Update. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The link for PendMoves is apparently broken, but MoveLater worked brilliantly. (Note to future readers: it must be run from the command line rather than simply double-clicking it.)

Comment: The link for MoveLater can be fixed by changing it to HTTPS, I attempted the edit, but it is "too minor" to be allowed...

Answer (score 0):

I was directed here because I wanted to see the pending updates before shutting down, but looking through the the filesystem for a log or xml file seemed unnecessary. After doing some digging turns out I was right. Although I found the same information in C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\ReportingEvents.log, you can simply follow these steps.

1. Open the event viewer.
2. Look for event ID 17 from source "WindowsUpdateClient."

You can now see the updates that have downloaded and will install when the computer is shutdown.